# How to properly merge ApplicationDbContext with your custom DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to do the following... When a `user` submits a new `article`, i want to display the authors (users) username in my web application. That's why i need to "connect" these two and i want to have only 1 DbContext.

Now i'm doing it this way:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    private DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; } // This line is all i have added/changed. Everything else was auto-generated when i created a new ASP.net MVC project with individual authentication in visual studio.

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

But i'm not sure if this is the right way to do it. How should this be done properly?

**UPDATE (explanation of my comment to DavidG's answer)**

First i was retrieving a list of users like this:

```
class ApplicationUserService
{
    public List<ApplicationUser> GetUsers()
    {
        using (var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            return dbContext.ApplicationUsers.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
class ApplicationUserService
{
    public List<IdentityUser> GetUsers()
    {
        using (var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            return dbContext.Users.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem was that i couldn't get the UserName or any other property because of this mistake. I watched some tutorials online, no one ever mentioned that the DbSet is Users. Anyways... now i know why i don't need this property:

```
public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

This message from VS helped me (intended for other people which should stumble upon the same problem i had):

```
'ApplicationDbContext.Users' hides inherited member 'IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser, IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>.Users'.
```

Comment: What is `ApplicationUser`? Is it inherited from `IdentityUser`?

Answer (score 3):

This is fine if you want to use one context, and the Identity tables are in the same database as your "article" table. I normally like to override OnModelCreating so I can add mapping/configurations for tables I create.

Depending on the size of the application, I leave the Identity context alone, and I create one for my application (I may include the Users table to make it easier to retrieve users). A matter of choice.

Answer (score 1):

Your application just needs to inherit from the correct version of the `IdentityDbContext` class. You need to use the generic one so you can customise the user class with your own `IdentityUser`. So you context should be like this. Note the new inheritance and removal of the `ApplicationUsers` property. This is removed as the `Identity` class already has this done for you.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    private DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

}
```

Comment: So how can i get a users details from db in your case? What's the DbSet name for the user?

Comment: Got it now i think. Please check my question again. And please confirm that the way i'm doing it now is correct. Thank you!